# Frame rate (cocos2d box2d) degradation in game scene

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

A game scene with multiple layer ant numerous sprite, working almost nicely(except of some problems). But if we put the game on hold, for a long time of 5-10 minutes (approx), it's frame rate goes down and game start giving jerky effect when been start playing again.

the default frame rate is been used initially here is default `ccMacros.h`:

```
#define CC_DIRECTOR_INIT()                                                                      \
do{                                                                                         \
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];                   \
if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )                             \
    [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeNSTimer];                                    \
CCDirector *__director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];                                       \
viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];               \
viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;                                                 \
[__director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];                                \
[__director setDisplayFPS:NO];                                                              \
[__director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];                                                   \
EAGLView *__glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]                                \
                                pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565                          \
                                depthFormat:0 /* GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES */                \
                         preserveBackbuffer:NO];                                            \
[__director setOpenGLView:__glView];                                                        \
[viewController setView:__glView];                                                          \
[window addSubview: viewController.view];                                                   \
[window makeKeyAndVisible];                                                                 \
} while(0)
```

Edit: The scenario is, **APPLICATION KEEP WORKING PROPERLY WHILE I'M PLAYING IT EVEN FOR THAN FIVE OR TEN MINUTES BUT FRAME RATE GET DOWN WHEN WE LEFT THE APPLICATION UN TOUCHED FOR THE SAME TIME PERIOD** SO is there any way to refresh the application time to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tried every thing, @Nitish suggested but, at a movement every thing got to be failed. As that **degradading frame rate is still an issue**. By googling too much and trying to find out the **reason** and solution, I have only been succeed to have reason only, as I was unable to afford solution. To check what I got, [CHECK THIS LINK](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/49017-cocos2d-strange-frame-rate-variation.html).

Answer (score 3):

Low frame is caused due to many reasons like inefficient memory usage, using `NSTimers`, drawing anything inside a scheduled selector, and many more. Make sure you are releasing the memory you are allocating.
Just have a look at below links which might help you increase the frame rate in your game:

- [**Gaining some FPS in your game**](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/36)
- [**BestPractices**](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/wiki/BestPractices)
- [**Improving performance**](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3abest_practices)

Comment: As i am not using NSTimer, and releasing memory properly(As there is no analyzer issue), But yea **drawing anything inside a scheduled selector** MAY CAUSE PROBLEM. IS THERE ANY PARTICULAR WAY TO RESOLVE THIS PROBLEM.

Comment: You can draw inside the draw selector.

Comment: I have checked for possibilities, but it's not helping, actually the scenario is, **APPLICATION KEEP WORKING PROPERLY WHILE I'M PLAYING IT EVEN FOR THAN FIVE OR TEN MINUTES BUT FRAME RATE GET DOWN WHEN WE LEFT THE APPLICATION UN TOUCHED FOR THE SAME TIME PERIOD** SO is there any way to refresh the application time to time?